Why is my authenticated state not updating properly?
I'm trying to redirect users to /feed after they log in, but even though console.log("Login successful") prints, the page doesn’t navigate to /feed. It seems like checkAuth() isn’t updating the authenticated state in time for Login.jsx to recognize it as true. Am I using async/await incorrectly, or is there an issue with my useEffect dependency on authenticated?
Here's the relevant code:
Context API methods:
const checkAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get("/authenticate-user");

      if (response.data.isAuthenticated) {
        setAuthenticated(true);
        setUser(response.data.user);
        setProfileUrl(`/profile/${response.data.user.id}`);
      } else {
        setAuthenticated(false);
        setUser(null);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during authentication check:", error.response);
      setAuthenticated(false);
      setUser(null);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  const handleLogin = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      await axiosInstance.post("/login", { email, password });

      // Check if login was successful
      await checkAuth();
      console.log("Login successful");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login:", error.response);
      toast.error("Invalid Credentials");
    }
  };

Login.jsx
export default function Login() {
  const { authenticated, handleLogin, setAuthenticated } = useContext(AppContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authenticated) {
      navigate("/feed");
    }
  }, [authenticated, navigate]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    const { email, password } = formData;

    await handleLogin(email, password);
    
    setFormData({
      email: "",
      password: "",
    });
    setLoading(false);
  };
// rest of the code
}

Why isn’t checkAuth() updating authenticated in time, and how can I ensure authenticated is correctly checked before Login.jsx attempts to navigate?

Are you sure setAuthenticated(true); is running and not setAuthenticated(false);? It'll log "Login successful" either way in your code even when setting it to false
